# Xpath: Check if node doesn't exist

Tags: java, xml, xpath, expression

I get the XML from my webshops API call structured much like the example below:

```
<Customers>
<Customer>
    <Username>userOne</Username>
    <Params>
        <Param>
            <Id>111</Id>
            <Name>Param1</Name>
            <Value><![CDATA[Param 1 is on]]></Value>
        </Param>
        <Param>
            <Id>112</Id>
            <Name>Param2</Name>
            <Value><![CDATA[OFF]]></Value>
        </Param>
    </Params>
</Customer>
<Customer>
    <Username>userTwo</Username>
    <Params>
        <Param>
            <Id>111</Id>
            <Name>Param1</Name>
            <Value><![CDATA[Param 1 is on]]></Value>
        </Param>
        <Param>
            <Id>112</Id>
            <Name>Param2</Name>
            <Value><![CDATA[OFF]]></Value>
        </Param>
    </Params>
</Customer>
<Customer>
    <Username>userThree</Username>
    <Params>            
        <Param>
            <Id>112</Id>
            <Name>Param2</Name>
            <Value><![CDATA[ON]]></Value>
        </Param>
    </Params>
</Customer>
```

There are way more parameters in them, ans the amount varies dependong on many outside factors.
I'm trying to get the usernames for when the values for id"111" and id"112" are what I'm looking for.
`Customers/Customer[Params/Param[Id/text()='111']/Value/text()='Param 1 is on'][Params/Param[Id/text()='112']/Value/text()='OFF']/Username/text()`

The above code returns "userOne" and "userTwo" as expected.

The problem is, that Id"111" either has the value "Param 1 is on" or nothing, and if it has no value it won't show up in the XML.
So I need an expression that checks if a node with id"111" doesn't exist and the value of id"112" is "ON".

Xpath is realy new to me unfortunatelly, and I couldn't find a way to check specificly if a node doesn't exist.

Comment: While asking an XPath question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XPath that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output based on the #1 above.
(4) XPath processor and its conformance with the XPath standards: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, or 3.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XPath `count(expr)`can be used to check the absence of a condition

```
Customers/Customer[count(Params/Param[Id/text()='111' and Value/text()='Param 1 is on']) = 0 and Params/Param[Id/text()='112']/Value/text()='ON']/Username/text()
```

So this part checks that that node does not exist
`count(Params/Param[Id/text()='111' and Value/text()='Param 1 is on']) = 0`
or
`count(Params/Param[Id/text()='111']) = 0`

AND this part checks the other expected condition
`Params/Param[Id/text()='112']/Value/text()='ON'`

Applied on the sample returns:
`userThree`

Answer (score 0):

Per definition a nodeset, when cast to boolean is true and only true if it has elements (https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/#dt-ebv). With that an existence check for the value element can look like

```
fn:boolean(Customers/Customer[Params/Param[Id/text()='111']/Value)
```

or if you want to include that in your check as a third alternative

```
Customers/Customer[Params/Param[Id/text()='111' and not ./Value]
```